# Child meta move makes the Stack Exchange app blow up

Tags: bug, android-app

[image: favorites]

The child meta sites have been renamed for the move to https.
As a side effect their names in the API changed, making the favorite sites in the app display "unknown site" in the list.

So far so good. Clicking that entry results in the standard crash message (Stack Exchange stopped working) and the app restarting.